# wcfGridChildObjectCheckboxViewer compile error for WebSphere Commerce 7's Management Center

Tags: websphere-commerce

I'm using WebSphere Commerce + it's Dev Environment's RAD, and have just made some changes to a promotion type. As a result, I have to rebuild the LOBTools project (Management Center is the main business tool I'm using). However, I'm now getting the following compile error:

`undefined superclass wcfGridTextViewer for class wcfGridChildObjectCheckboxViewer` in the `Checkbox.lzx` file.
There are other files in the exact same folder that extend the same class, and those are compiling just fine...

I've had a look around, and others have had the [exact same problem](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014618789&ps=25), and the only two fixes described, I've been unable to get to work...

I'm hoping somebody here has seen this before, and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a question for IBM Software Support.   Submit a PMR and they'll help you fix it.